# How do I set the hostname of a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, hostname

There are several questions similar to what I'm trying to do here, but I can't find any that actually answer the question. Feel free to just link me if you find one.

I need to set the hostname of a Windows 7 machine. In Linux, it's a simple

```
hostname mymachine.mydomain.com
```

But on Windows, I can't figure out how to set my hostname to this without having an actual domain set up called `mydomain.com`.

Is it possible to do this? I have a DNS domain called `mydomain.com` but it is not a Windows active directory domain, so when I try to set it in the Network ID menu in `sysdm.cpl`, it doesn't recognize the domain and fails to connect.

Is there a simple way to do this in Windows?

Comment: If you are connected to a wireless router or devices that hands out IP addresses some do tend to set a domain or hostname as .local - go into the router settings (if you have access to it) and see if there are any options to change the domain.

Comment: "*...so when I try to set it in the Network ID menu in*" sounds like that sentence is incomplete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hostname is just that: a **hostname**. It is never supposed to have more than one component within it. The FQDN can be determined by appending the configured DNS domain, according to `resolv.conf`.

*sysdm.cpl → Computer Name → Change → More...* has a "Primary DNS suffix" option, which might be helpful here.

Additionally, in Windows networks, you're facing the issue that Microsoft uses the term *domain* also to describe part of their Windows ecosystem. Namely, the [Windows domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain).
Interestingly though, the Windows domain will also provide the [Domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) for all hosts on the Windows network.